# JSF, writeAttribute("value", str, null) fails with strings obtained through ValueExpression.getValue()

Tags: java, jsf

I'm having a somewhat weird problem with custom JSF component.

Here's my renderer code:

```
public class Test extends Renderer {

 public void encodeBegin(final FacesContext context,
                        final UIComponent component) throws IOException {

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

        writer.startElement("textarea", component);

        String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
        if (clientId != null)
              writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, null);

        ValueExpression exp = component.getValueExpression("value");
        if (exp != null && exp.getValue(context.getELContext()) != null) {
              String val = (String) exp.getValue(context.getELContext());
              System.out.println("Value: " + val);
              writer.writeAttribute("value", val,  null);
        }

    writer.endElement("textarea");
    writer.flush();
 }
}
```

The code generates:

```
<textarea name="j_id2:j_id12:j_id19" value=""></textarea>
```

Property binding contains "test" and as it should be, "Value: test" is successfully printed to console.

Now, if I change the code to:

```
public void encodeBegin(final FacesContext context,
                        final UIComponent component) throws IOException {

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

        writer.startElement("textarea", component);

        String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
        if (clientId != null)
             writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, null);

        ValueExpression exp = component.getValueExpression("value");
        if (exp != null && exp.getValue(context.getELContext()) != null) {
             String val = (String) exp.getValue(context.getELContext());
             String str = "new string";
             System.out.println("Value1: " + val + ", Value2: " + str);
             writer.writeAttribute("value", str,  null);
        }

        writer.endElement("textarea");
        writer.flush();
 }
```

generated html is:

```
<textarea name="j_id2:j_id12:j_id19" value="new string"></textarea>
```

and console output is "Value1: test, Value2: new string"

What's going on here? This doesn't make sense. Why would writeAttribute differentiate between the two strings?

Additional info:

- The component extends UIComponentBase
- I am using it with facelets

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) element doesn't have a "value" attribute. Actually, the element's body is the value. You should end up with

```
<textarea name="j_id2:j_id12:j_id19">new string</textarea>
```

Have a look in the original JSF TextAreaRenderer source code for more hints.

Comment: Then we test to see if @ccomet will work on a really old one.